# How long should it takes before I can consider an outgoing transaction that is still in pending as failed?

Tags: transaction, wallet, pending, double-spending

This is a different question born from the discussion in ["How do I know if a pending transaction will be successful?"](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-do-i-know-if-a-pending-transaction-will-be-successful/)

I'd like to know **WHEN** I have the green light to try to do a second transaction in case the first one is still in pending.

Please explain any differences (if any) from using the Light Wallet (computer) or the Android Wallet (smartphone).

Comment: My initial question was about the time I have to wait before considering a transaction failed, not if I can or cannot make a double spend. It is a bit different I feel.

Answer (score 7):

There is no green light. If you sign a transaction a second time, even if it is pending, you reveal your private key and the address is insecure. All remaining funds on that address might get stolen.
The light wallet on your computer prevents you from doing that. The Android wallet doesn't.

The only way to get out of this situation is to promote (as often as you want) or reattach (every 30 min) the transaction, until the transaction is not pending anymore. To maximize your chances you should choose the best accessable node. Best node is found at the top of the list on [iota.dance/nodes](http://iota.dance/nodes)

Comment: Today I met a guy. 6 Gi were stolen, because he did a double spend.

Comment: And so how you can get out from this loop? You have to change seed and address, but cannot move founds out of your acutal wallet because you have another transactoin always in pending. So how?

Answer (score 4):

A transaction will likely remain pending if it doesn't confirm within ~ 1 hour. That is just a rough estimation and may change in the future. Anyone can reattach it, so it will have another chance to get confirmed.

Never resend (reusing the address which is bad), always reattach until confirmed.
The current GUI wallet 2.5.4 throws a warning if you try to resend, and keeps you from sending. The Android wallet sadly does not.

Comment: this is a more clear answer at the moment. So, what should I do if I want to move my funds but I get stuck with a pending transaction?

Comment: Reattach every hour until confirmed.