# What does the `security` param for `getNewAddress` do?

Tags: security, address, iri-legacy-api

When I create addresses in the API library (i.e., using `getNewAddress()`), there is an optional `security` parameter.

What does this parameter do, and what values does it accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the "Security level to be used for the private key / address. Can be 1, 2 or 3."

A security level determines the number of rounds for hashing, or in other words the length of the private key.

- Security level 1 : key length 81 trits (security low)
- Security level 2 : key length 162 trits (security medium)
- Security level 3 : key length 243 trits (security high)

Related reading:

- [here](https://domschiener.gitbooks.io/iota-guide/content/chapter1/seeds-private-keys-and-addresses.html) for the doc
- [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.java/blob/master/jota/src/main/java/jota/utils/Signing.java) for the code

Comment: I think this is not correct. The **length** of the private key is [security] * 2187 Trytes, as opposed to [security] * 81 Trits. Am I correct?